# How do I activate word wrapping in text editor in Aptana Studio?

Tags: eclipse, word-wrap, aptana

How do I activate line wrapping in text editor in Aptana Studio?

I'm interested about wrapping in view mode (in order to not have to do horizontal scrolling).

Answer (score 65):

Tried right-clicking within the editor and selecting ‘word wrap’ from the context menu?

Comment: Hand... Face... Slap. It's one of those situations where you expect it to be hard to find so you skip the obvious places...

Comment: @Robertson Odom It works, but is there any way to make turn word wrap on as a default?

Answer (score 28):

On Main Menu click "Window" choose "Preferences". In left-side list, click "Aptana Studio". An alphabetical list on right side will show. Select "Editors" then check "Enable word wrap (requires restart)".

[image]

It seems to work on the latest version of Aptana as well. [Here](http://blog.emobilez.com/2009/02/16/how-to-turn-on-word-wrap-in-aptana-studio/) are some screenshots of where you can find such option.

Comment: Frustratingly filtering for "wrap" does not seem to reveal this option. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you would think "wrap" would bring up an the section in the editor with "wrap" in it!

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and you can right click anywhere in the code and select Word Wrap which should be the second last option.

Comment: I dont see this when I click anywhere  on a .js file. But if I right click and the file is either .html or .php, I do see the Word Wrap option...

Comment: @gerl python does not support? why

Comment: Excellent. Works fine!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2 and found that 'word wrap' can be change with in editor from context menu, BUT only if the mouse are on line number field! If the mouse is on text editor the option 'word wrap' missing. This change only setting for current opened file. It will be good to change default option !

Answer (score 0):

```
Window > Preferences > Aptana > Editors...
```

Actually **click on the word "Editors"**, you don't need to click the "+" symbol next to it.  Once that loads, go to the "Advanced" tab, and you should see the option you're looking for to enable word wrap.

Found that here.
http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=7482

Once you restart, you should be good to go.

Comment: There is no "Advanced" option in the latest Aptana Studio.

Comment: Edited accordingly.  After the "Aptana" step, click on the word "Editors", and then look for the "Advanced" tab.

Comment: I'm using 3.0 beta and there is no Advanced tab.