# Aptana: Flickering Scrollbar - no bug progress

Tags: scrollbar, aptana, flicker

I have issues with Aptana (3.6.0.201...658) on dark themes. Every time I hit the cursor, the horizontal scroll bar in the workspace flickers into view and out again. This seems to be a bug, which has been reported already a long time ago:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8138

Has anyone else found a solution? Makes working in Aptana incredibly annoying.

Comment: This is a known bug, they might fix it in 3.6.1 release. Hopefully it will come soon. Flickering scroll bar is super annoying!

Answer (score 2):

Most simple workaround is to simply activate the word wrap feature.
Right click in the work space to get the context menu, then activate word wrap: 
[How do I activate word wrapping in text editor in Aptana Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990550/how-do-i-activate-word-wrapping-in-text-editor-in-aptana-studio)

Comment: Tried both right-click 'Word wrap' and Preferences > Editors > Word Wrap = ON. Didn't solve the issue :(

Comment: You have to restart the Editor before starts word... wrapping, I think that's how you can say it.

Comment: The thing it's that I haaaaaaaate word wrap XD And they don't seem to be repairing any bug...

Comment: I hate wordwrap and I hate flickering scrollbar!, what should I do? :)

Comment: hate wordwrap.  Using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 RC3 (4.4.2) - March 2015 because the standard free edition couldn't install the Aptana plug-in at all.  This is hopeless: flicker, slow keystrokes.  Is Eclipse the new Microsoft?